# Sharepoint Workflow doesn't trigger after created/edited tickets

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a workflow created in Sharepoint designer that works fine when manually triggered.  I want it to trigger when a new ticket is created and when an existing ticket is edited.  I have tried everything, but it makes no sense that it works when manually triggered, but does not appear to trigger when tickets are created/modified.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating a work flow (first screen) you can see three check boxes

1. Allow this workflow to be manually started from an item.
2. Automatically start this workflow when a new item is created.
3. Automatically start this workflow when ever an item is changed.

You might have choosen the first option only. So that you need to start it manually. You have to opt the three options

also what do you mean "I have tried everything".